# "Request::is()" not working on laravel 5.5, in blade

Tags: laravel, url, request

I am trying to set active classes on active menus. In the past I was using **Request::is()** function for this, but in the new version of laravel it says *"Class 'Request' not found."*

Comment: did you include `Request` share you code where you are using ?

Comment: how can I include it in blade? I was using facade in the past.

Comment: why you said this `In the past I was using Request::is()` ?

Comment: Because I did :) I am still using that in the laravel 5.2 and it works fine. now in new laravel when I am using Request class in blade I get the not found error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using `blade` you can use [`request`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-request) helper method. Try like this

```
request()->is('your_url');
```

Comment: I just checked in version 5.5 and it is working in blade `{{Request::is('admin')?'True':'False'}}` for url `localhost/admin`.

Answer (score 2):

do not put / before the route. 
it should be like

```
@if(Request::is('index'))
    @include('include.showcase')
@endif
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.[Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Arguments to a function make no difference if the user is getting a "class not found" error.

Answer (score 0):

please check in your code

you add this line as namespace or not

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

and you can also pass one varriable with view from controller side and check on blade template if you get that data then you can use active class for that menu. like this

in controller what i had used in my project

```
            $data['page-tab'] = 'adduser';
            return view('user.add_user',compact('data'));
```

and in blade file i had checked this like this in sidebar section

```
 <li class="{{ isset($data['page-tab']) && $data['page-tab'] == 'adduser' ? 'active' : '' }}"><a href="{{ route('adduser') }}"><i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i>Manage Member</a></li>
```

hope this works for you.

Comment: well, it would work I guess, but I am searching for a better and cleaner solution, because  I have a bit complicated menus.

Answer (score 0):

Use it without the '/'
like this:

```
@Request::is('home')
```

not

```
@request::is('/home')
```

Comment: How does this help resolve the "class not found" error the OP was getting 4 years ago?